# Did not find handler method for [/upload]

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a controller that is used to read an excel file.
 Here is the controller

```
    @RestController
@MultipartConfig(location="/tmp",
        fileSizeThreshold=0,
        maxFileSize=5242880,       // 5 MB
        maxRequestSize=20971520)   // 20 MB
public class UploadController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Upload mappings excel file", notes = "Uploads the excel file and stores on couchbase")

    @ApiResponses(value = {

            @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "File uploaded successfully"),

            @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error"),

            @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "Bad request")

    })

    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.PUT, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = "multipart/form-data")
        public void uploadMappingsExcel (@ApiParam(value = "file", example = "user.ods", required = true)
                                             @RequestParam(value = "file", required = false) MultipartFile multipartFile) throws IOException{
        Path  path = null;
        for(MultipartFile file : Collections.singleton(multipartFile)) {
            path = Paths.get(file.getOriginalFilename());
            Files.write(path,file.getBytes());
        }

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(path.toString());
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                String cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
                System.out.print(cellValue + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();

        }

        }
```

When i try to run it through postman I get an error Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause and some logs as

Did not find handler method for [/upload]
 Looking for handler method for path [/upload]
Looking up handler method for path /error
Did not find handler method for /error

[Here is the code structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko38q.png)

[Postman Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKysH.png)

[The Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx1yD.png)

Comment: You are trying to read or upload excel file ?

Can you add the details about the request you are sending through postman ?

I'm seeing `method = RequestMethod.PUT` If you are trying to upload  file, may be you should have `method = RequestMethod.POST`

Comment: Same output with Post request as well.

Comment: Added the Postman In the edit

Comment: Check the start up logs for any issues.You should see it regiestering the rest of the mappings

Comment: added the logs as well, As i have been looking at the same for the last 5-6 hours but still am not able to figure out what is the issue. Maybe i am missing out some minor detail

Comment: it is hitting your controller. its failing with a Null Pointer on whatever line 55 is

Comment: path = Paths.get(file.getOriginalFilename());              This is the line 55 . It is in the code above